# Can anyone please explain, how to create new form for specific sharepoint list view through OOB feature

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-online

I have list name called Newlist with 3 columns respectively EmpName, EmpAge, EmpPhone number.

I have created a view called Myview with 2 columns respectively Empname, EmpPhone.

Now i added this Myview as listview webpart in my page.

When i add new item using that view it is showing 3 columns in the new form, But i need only two columns in the new form.

Please assist with me how to do that?

Answer (score 1):

Make sure the third column you don't with to show is not mandatory. Then modify the New form (or create new form and make it default) of the list using SharePoint Designer. In that form, remove or hide the field table row in question. Step by details [here](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/23955.sharepoint-2013-building-custom-forms.aspx#Building_the_form).

Not that this will make the field hidden in all cases, so you won't be able to add any value for this third field when creating new form. You can edit the value if editing the item after initial creation.

Comment: Thank you for your response. Is it possible to assign separate new form for the specific view ?

Comment: Not for a specific view unless you create additional button somewhere that links to specific view OR override the existing New Item button with some JavaScript and make it point to your custom form. I'd probably just inject some JS inside Script Editor that modifies the New Item link.